# Displaying data json , into web pages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I found the problem will display the results jSon to a web page at run time data is empty or blank web page, if anyone could help me ?

This my variable declare

```html
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://adisapu10022.besaba.com/smsVerify/json.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**This my function**

```html
  function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
            arr[i].Foto +
            "</td><td>" +
      arr[i].Komoditas +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Harga +
            "</td><td>" +
      arr[i].Pengunggah +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Telp +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Unggah +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing your json string is invalid. Check at

> ```
> "Komoditas":"Sepatu Nike",{"Harga":"900 Ribu /kg"
> ```

The right format is

> ```
> "Komoditas":"Sepatu Nike","Harga":"900 Ribu /kg"
> ```

Comment: okay thanks, I was less careful. the problem is now how to display the pictures that were taken from the url?

Comment: My guestimate is that you have to use `arr[i].Foto` in an `img` tag such as `"<img src='" + arr[i].Foto + "'/>`. Can you show us me the full json string so I can help?